# Google Tag Manager referral hostname

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have 2 hotel websites on their own domains with individual GA tracking codes which both use the same booking engine, also on a standalone domain. The booking engine can only use 1 GTM container, so both hotel websites also have to use the same GTM container with the aim to track the ecommerce.

I've used a page view tag with a hostname lookup variable which pushes the correct GA tracking code on each website which works fine. Problem is tracking the ecommerce.

I've tried using a URL fragment so if they are on www.bookingengine.com/hotel1 then it would assign the correct GA tracking code, but that doesn't work.

What I need is the tag manager to know the referral hostname if you are on the booking engine and change the GA tracking code used dynamically, so it matches the correct referral website. Is this possible?

Comment: "Does not work" is not really a good description. In what way does it fail?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Referrel-Hostname by using the Browser-API `document.referrer`. This gives you the Page the User came from.

Take this as an Javascript Variable and build a Trigger based on the Variable:

{{referrer}} regexp abc.com